# How to merge two sorted array in o(1) space complexity?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have two sorted arrays, I have to merge two sorted arrays into one without using extra space?
I was checking [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/efficiently-merging-two-sorted-arrays-with-o1-extra-space/) solution but I am unable to understand it.

**Example**

```
Input: ar1[] = {10};
       ar2[] = {2, 3};
Output: ar1[] = {2}
        ar2[] = {3, 10}  

Input: ar1[] = {1, 5, 9, 10, 15, 20};
       ar2[] = {2, 3, 8, 13};
Output: ar1[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9}
        ar2[] = {10, 13, 15, 20}
```

Comment: What specifically do you not understand about the solution?

Comment: Take a look at [std::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)

Comment: Well, the sample "C++" solution is a C solution.  That sort of sucks.

Comment: If it is the logic/algorithm you don't understand, c++ tag should be removed. If it is some part of the "C++" solution, show appropriate code.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why that algo works.

Comment: That's not merging two arrays into one, it's distributing the elements, in order, into the two arrays.

Comment: The algorithm looks a lot like shellsort, but with the input separated into two arrays.

Comment: You can trivially do it with any in place sorting algorithm, but if doing it with constant space overhead and linear time is even possible is the subject academic research, see in place mergesort.

Comment: Not a duplicate, this is for merging 2 sorted arrays.  Whereas the other question is for mergesort of an unsorted array.

Answer (score 1):

I'll solve it for the slightly simpler case of "the two arrays are already in one buffer".

```
// requires: array is a pointer to a buffer of numbers,
// such that from [array, array+middle) is sorted, and [array+middle, array+length)
// is also sorted.
void merge_inplace( int* array, int length );

// This halves the number "gap", rounding up.  Unless the value was 1, in
// which case it returns 0.
int nextgap( int gap ) {
  if (gap==1) return 0;
  return (gap+1)/2;
}

void merge_inplace( int* array, int length ) {
  int gap = nextgap(length); // about half of length

  while (gap != 0)
  {
    int left = 0;
    int right = left+gap;
    while (right < length) {
      // ensure elements at left and right are in correct relative order:
      if (array[left] > array[right])
        std::swap(array[left], array[right]);
      // advance:
      ++left;
      ++right;
    }
    // repeat on a gap half-ish the size:
    gap = nextgap(gap);
  }
}
```

now operating on two different arrays requires some extra work/logic, but that is mainly about fiddling with the indexes.

The point is that when you have two arrays that are sorted and next to each other, one pass of this "merge far apart, then closer together" algorithm (which has log-length count of subloops; so O(n lg n) steps) is enough to sort it.

Comment: `std::swap` is c++, the OP tagged the question as `c`

Comment: @chqr the OP edited the solution to requiest C hours after  I answerd it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple algorithm:

- while last element of `ar1` is larger than `ar2[0]`:

  - swap them.
  - shift the last element of `ar1` to its place in `ar1`,
  - shift the first element of `ar2` to its place in `ar2`,
  - repeat

The space complexity is **O(1)**, the time complexity is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

Comment: O(n2) is a too bad time to this task. This problem can be solved without any shifts. That's a part of merge-sort algo.

Comment: This is the right answer, force them to list all the requirements!

Comment: @Skident: Of course **O(n2)** is bad, but the requirement for **O(1)** space complexity is very strong. With **O(n)** extra space, the time complexity drops to **O(n)** too.

Comment: There is a faster algorithm with O(1) extra space, but it is very complex. It involves dividing the arrays into sqrt(n) segments, using the first segment as a buffer.  See the research paper: "Practical in-place merging" by BC Huang, MA Langston, 1988.  https://doi.org/10.1145/42392.42403

Answer (score 0):

In your examples the arrays are re-sorted. Is it what you need to do?

For this problem you can use the next algorithm:

1. Use a for loop from 0 to the length of the `array1`
2. Compare elements from the `array1` and the `array2`
3. If an element of the `array2` is less than an element of the `array1` then swap them
4. Iterate over the `array2` to find a better place of just swapped element

Algorithm:

```
void reorder(std::vector<int>& arr1, std::vector<int>& arr2)
{
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < arr1.size(); )
    {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        std::swap(arr1[i], arr2[j]);

        // find a better place for a swapped element in array 2
        for (size_t k = j, l = k+1; l < arr2.size(); k++, l++)
        {
            if (arr2[k] < arr2[l])
                break;
            std::swap(arr2[k], arr2[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

This algorithm can be improved...

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work as explained.

Comment: well, yes the solution is bit more complicated but as both arrays are sorted we do not need to do O(n2)

Comment: the code posted in your answer has **O(n2)** time complexity, even as both arrays are sorted already.